# Windows Store App Localized App Bar Buttons Guideline

Tags: localization, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Store Application. We are using the Multilingual App Toolkit to translate the resources in our app, including the AppBarButtons.

The trouble comes in that some translations of even simple phrases in some languages are incredibly long. What do we do for these buttons? They are near useless if half of the label is ellipsis-ed away ("My bu...").

I've search through the guidelines for what to do in this case and can't seem to find what they expect of us, or what is the best practice for this situation. Should I extend out the width of the buttons? In some cases I have the space to do this. In others, it will make it a bit cramped or I will have to make the buttons not uniform width, which can look bad. Do I make them word wrap? This still cuts some words mid-way in some languages, and can look pretty bad in my opinion. One way to improve that seems to be to align the buttons `Top`, but that still doesn't fix the mid-word wrap issue.

Does anyone know what the guidelines are for this? Or have any tips as to best practices?

[I'd like to note that, while a part of this question requests opinions as to best practice, the main question I'd like answered is for a guideline specified by Microsoft, as I haven't been able to find one.]

Comment: Personally I think that app bar is not a good control at all. It's not very fast in access and as you see it's limited in features. Even Microsoft started replacing appbar with context menus (in the upcoming Windows Blue update). So, maybe you can use some different control instead of app bar? As microsoft guidelines says, appbar is main action and navigation control, there shouldn't be long and complex commands.

Comment: Even something as simple as "Add Thing" in some languages is quite long.

Comment: You can use icon to present the "Thing" and use only short annotation in text like "Add".

Comment: It's a bit more difficult than that, unfortunately, but I take your point.